# Feedback on JS that drags elements around page and saves styles to localStorage?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a script to allow a user to drag a `div` around the page and save it's position and style to `localStorage`, and I'm wondering if there's anything I can do to make the script more efficient. I have posted the code below, but I left out the drag functionality because I'd like to work on that myself, but the rest I'd like feedback on.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Load function (10 steps)
    function loadDiv() {
        $(".base").each(function () { // (1) Find each div with the class of base
            var id = $(this).attr("id"); // (2) Get the id from the element and set it to a variable
            var counter = localStorage.getItem("counter-" + id) || 0; // (3) See if counter is at 0 and get each LS key with the syntax (counter-(2))
            var active = localStorage.getItem(id + "-active") || ""; // (4) Get each LS key with the syntax ((2)-active) and see if it's undefined
            $.each(active.split(" "), function (k, v) {
                var s = v.split(","); // (5) Split each variable from (4) with K = Key and V = Value
                if (s.length != 2) { // (6) Check if length is not equal to 2
                    return; // (7) Do nothing
                }
                var newElement = $("#" + s[0]).clone(); // (8) Set the element that's getting cloned to a variable
                newElement.attr("id", s[1]).attr("class", "drag " + id).data("id", id).appendTo("body"); // (9) Clone element
            });
        });
        dragWidget(); // (10) Initialize dragging for these elements
    }
    // Set CSS function (5 steps)
    function setCSS() {
        $(".drag").each(function () { // (1) Find all divs on the page with the class drag
            var id = $(this).not(".base").attr("id"); // (2) Set then id of each div that's not .base to a variable
            $(this).css({
                "left": localStorage.getItem(id + "-x"), // (3) Retrieve localStorage item with the variable from (2) and append -x to the end to get and set left offset
                "top": localStorage.getItem(id + "-y"), // (4) Retrieve localStorage item with the variable from (2) and append -y to the end to get and set top offset
                "z-index": localStorage.getItem(id + "-z"), // (5) Retrieve localStorage item with the variable from (2) and append -z to the end to get and set the z-index
            });
        });
    }
    // Close function (7 steps)
    function closeDiv() {
        var id = $(this).parent().attr("id").match(/[a-zA-Z]+/g); // (1) Get only the first word from the parent element and assign it to a variable
        $(this).parent().remove(); // (2) Remove the parent element
        var active = []; // (3) Set the active variable to a blank array
        $($("." + id).not(".base")).each(function () { // (4) Go through every element that's not .base
            active.push(id + "," + $(this).attr("id")); // (5) Add each element to an array with the syntax ((1),(1)+id from element)
        });
        active = active.join(" "); // (6) Join the array together by a space
        localStorage.setItem(id + "-active", active); // (7) Set the LS item with the syntax ((1)-active, (5))
    }
    // Clone function (13 steps)
    function cloneDiv() {
        var id = $(this).attr("href").match(/[a-zA-Z]+/g); // (1) Get only the first word from the parent element and assign it to a variable
        var key = "counter-" + id; // (2) Set a variable with the syntax "counter-(1)"
        var counter = localStorage.getItem(key) || 0; // (3) Get the LS item with the name (2) and see if it's equal to 0
        counter++; // (4) Add one to the counter
        var newElement = $("#" + id).clone(); // (5) Set clone parameters to a variable
        newElement.attr("id", id + counter).attr("class", "drag " + id).appendTo("body"); // (6) Duplicate the div to the body
        var active = []; // (7) Set the active variable to an array
        $($("." + id).not(".base")).each(function () { // (8) Get all elements that match ".(1)" that aren't ".base" and loop through them
            active.push(id + ',' + $(this).attr("id")); // (9) Add each element to an array with the syntax ((1),(1)+id from element)
        });
        active = active.join(" "); // (10) Join the array together by a space
        localStorage.setItem(id + "-active", active); // (11) Set the LS item with the syntax ((1)-active, (7))
        localStorage.setItem(key, counter); // (12) Set the LS item with the syntax ((2), (4))
        dragWidget(); // (13) Enable dragging
    }
    // Clear localStorage (2 steps)
    function clearLocalstorage() {
        localStorage.clear(); // (1) Clear all localStorage items
        location.reload(); // (2) Reload the page
    }
    loadDiv();
    setCSS();
    $(".close").click(closeDiv);
    $(".nav a").click(cloneDiv);
    $(".clear a").click(clearLocalstorage);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks ok so far. Here are some tips.

## 1)

Only provide comments for sections arounds complex code. Also, it's best to place comment directly above the statements and not side by side.

Bad:

```
$(".base").each(function () { // (1) Find each div with the class of base
    var id = $(this).attr("id"); // (2) Get the id from the element and set it to a variable
```

Better:

```
// (1) Find each div with the class of base
$(".base").each(function () { 
    // (2) Get the id from the element and set it to a variable
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
```

Best:

```
$(".base").each(function () { 
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
```

## 2)

Not really needed but I think you should create a function for creating the `active` string.

Old Code:

```
//...
var active = [];
$($("." + id).not(".base")).each(function () {
    active.push(id + "," + $(this).attr("id"));
});
active = active.join(" ");

//...
var active = [];
$($("." + id).not(".base")).each(function () {
    active.push(id + "," + $(this).attr("id"));
});
active = active.join(" ");
//...
```

New Code:

```
var getActiveIdStr = function( id ){
    var active = [];
    $($("." + id).not(".base")).each(function () {
        active.push(id + ',' + $(this).attr("id"));
    });
    return active.join(" ");
}
//...
getActiveIdStr( id );
//...
getActiveIdStr( id );
```

## 3)

Here's a tip on how to store objects to `localStorage`. The trick is to use `JSON.stringify` to set values and `JSON.parse` to retrieve values. [More here:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage)

Code:

```
var lsHelper = {};
lsHelper.set = function (key, value) {
    if (typeof value === "object") {
        value = JSON.stringify(value);
    }
    localStorage.setItem(key, value);
};
lsHelper.get = function (key) {
    var value = localStorage.getItem(key);
    if (value && value[0] === "{") {
        value = JSON.parse(value);
    }
    return value;
};
```

## 4)

The easiest way to save the positions of draggable elements is to use `localStorage` and the module ["Draggable"](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Draggable) from the jQuery UI project.
Use `lsHelper` to save the position once an element is dropped. Then when the page is refreshed, use the `create` option in `Draggable` to re-position all the draggable elements by the positions saved in `localStorage`.

HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

        Load using Script Tag: "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"
        Load using Script Tag: "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"

  <style type="text/css">
  .dragMe { width: 100px; height: 70px; background: silver; }
  </style>
</head>
<body style="font-size:62.5%;">

<div id="draggable1" class="dragMe">1: Drag me</div>
<div id="draggable2" class="dragMe">2: Drag me</div>

</body>
</html>
```

JS Code:

```
var ls = ls || {};
ls.set = function (key, value) {
    if (typeof value === "object") {
        value = JSON.stringify(value);
    }
    localStorage.setItem(key, value);
};
ls.get = function (key) {
    var value = localStorage.getItem(key);
    if (value && value[0] === "{") {
        value = JSON.parse(value);
    }
    return value;
};

$(function () {
    $(".dragMe").draggable({
        create : function (event, ui) {
            var position = ls.get("position:" + $(this).attr("id"));
            if(position){
                $(this).offset( position );
            }
        },
        stop : function (event, ui) {             
            var currentPos = ui.helper.position();
            ls.set("position:" + $(this).attr("id"), currentPos);
        }
    });
});
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/DLM3n/

Comment: Do you think using `regex` is fine though?

Comment: Yeah it's ok, but in `cloneDiv()` you should use `$(this).parent().attr("href")` instead of `$(this).attr("href")` to get the parent element.